# Heroku and Django giving a 500 error when Debug is not set to False

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I have been following and checking every forum post, setup instruction and video I can find. I've been checking git hub repos and comparing to my code. I cannot get my Django application to run on Heroku with DEBUG set to false and not get a 500 server error. So I wanted to reach out to ask two questions:

1. How critical is it that I have DEBUG set to False? I have seen that it could expose information but the application is more of an online resume/portfolio site ("Hey, this is some information about me and here are some small apps I've made")
2. Could someone take a look at my code and see what I am missing ( https://github.com/seanhayes13/codingHavoc )? I'm not using any databases for this part of the app

Thank you

If DEBUG is set to False, 500 error. If DEBUG is set to True, everything runs fine. I have the Heroku recommended if block setting the ALLOWED_HOSTS to ['*']. All of the static files (style sheets, pages and images) are loading fine

I'm not seeing any error, here are the logs from heroku (I'm still new to working with Heroku, just started this up over the weekend, so if I'm missing something, any help would be grateful):

```
2023-11-20T21:52:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2023-11-20T21:53:04.948007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.codinghavoc.com request_id=30d8e0bb-cc1b-41d1-a190-3f6f862f0c1a fwd="71.218.128.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=377ms status=500 bytes=459 protocol=http

2023-11-20T21:53:04.947814+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.40.105 - - [20/Nov/2023:21:53:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"

2023-11-20T21:53:05.038202+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.40.105 - - [20/Nov/2023:21:53:05 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "http://www.codinghavoc.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"

2023-11-20T21:53:05.038564+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.codinghavoc.com request_id=fb66d104-6432-42cd-b1c8-7bee66a0df4d fwd="71.218.128.197" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=467 protocol=http
```

Also, when I pull up the main page, I get the 500 error. When I force and go to [www.codinghavoc.com/about](http://www.codinghavoc.com/about) or /projects, those pages load just fine, it's only when trying to access the main page that I get the 500

Comment: Catch the error raised and share

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your questions:

1. You can use `DEBUG = True` during development but it is recommended that you set `DEBUG = False` in a production environment. This is because setting `DEBUG = True` in a production environment can produce a lot of output that may cause your website to be slow. It can also cause bad impression to the user by exposing the internal architecture of your server.
2. This should work. copy and paste this configuration settings in your `settings.py` file.

```
# Configure Django App for Heroku.
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())

# Debug settings for Heroku environment
if os.environ.get('DEBUG') == 'TRUE':
    DEBUG = True
elif os.environ.get('DEBUG') == 'FALSE':
    DEBUG = False
```